# How to apply the following style on an element?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have  a element in angular2 app as follows,

```
 <div class="ticket-card" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + ticketPath + ')' , 'background-size':  'cover'}">
```

with the above style, i want to add the following style,

```
background: 
    / top, transparent red / 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    )

}
```

Comment: I don't know angular.. but I wonder why you need a gradient if the color stops are **identical**?

Comment: no they are different just want to apply the style

Comment: component does not render when i run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.gradient = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1))";
}]);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-style="{'background': gradient}"></div>
```

Use basic angular syntax to insert string into `ngStyle` directive.

Comment: my question is how to apply with the element. this is wrong answer